# setfocusableInTouchMode vs onClick

Tags: android, android-layout

I have menu button in screen,i set `setfocusableInTouchMode` and `onclick` for menu Button.If i click the menu button it getting focused and second click only getting fired.I want to do both operation at a time.

Answer (score 0):

call  RequestFocus on your Button followed by performClick() this will focus and also fire click event on your Button .